# Div width won't adjust to sit next to floating image

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm having difficulty getting a div containing text to reduce it's width in order to wrap nicely next to an image that's floated right. The text inside the div is behaving as I would like it to but the grey div is stretching behind the image.

The div/box is part of a wordpress shortcode plugin. I don't know whether that is complicating matters

Here is the css for the elements in question

---

**Image:**

```
.circular-image-right img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    clear: both;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 30px 60px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

---

**Div:**

```
element.style {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

 .symple-box.gray {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    color: #666666;
}

.symple-box {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 30px 15px 5px;
}
```

---

The page in question can be seen here:

http://c3927181.myzen.co.uk/

Comment: hi, did you find a solution to your issue? did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/iLAMuXoc/5/edit?css,output

```
.symple-box.gray { 
  padding: 16px 30px; 
  margin: 0 360px 0 0;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F9F9F9; 
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; 
  color: #666666;
}
```

Comment: I removed the "div" tag that wrapped your "ul".  Take a look at the html.